# Room Query returns empty list

Tags: database, kotlin, android-room

i am trying to fetch my data from my Room database . I have 2 rows in my Sqlite table "entertainment" . I dont know why everytime my list returns size 0 . So i cannot access my database. I have tested to that if my code can see my asset folder with onOpen and onCreate Methods and i can get logs successfully . I have checked my table and column names also . Here is my database :

[[image: Rows and columns][1]]

sqlite query :

```
CREATE TABLE "entertainment" (
    "id"    INTEGER,
    "categoryId"    INTEGER,
    "difficulty"    INTEGER,
    "title1"    TEXT,
    "title2"    TEXT,
    "title3"    TEXT,
    "title4"    TEXT,
    "title5"    TEXT,
    "imageUrl1" TEXT,
    "imageUrl2" TEXT,
    "imageUrl3" TEXT,
    "imageUrl4" TEXT,
    "imageUrl5" TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY("id" AUTOINCREMENT)
);
```

my data class :

```
@Entity(tableName = "entertainment")
data class Entertainment(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) @ColumnInfo(name = "id") val id: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "categoryId") val categoryId : Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "difficulty") val difficulty: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "title1") val title1: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "title2") val title2: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "title3") val title3: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "title4") val title4: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "title5") val title5: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "imageUrl1") val imageUrl1: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "imageUrl2") val imageUrl2: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "imageUrl3") val imageUrl3: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "imageUrl4") val imageUrl4: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "imageUrl5") val imageUrl5: String
)
```

AppDatabase :

```
@Database(entities = [Entertainment::class], version = 1)
abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    // Define your DAOs here
    abstract fun entertainmentDao(): EntertainmentDao

    companion object {
        @Volatile
        private var INSTANCE: AppDatabase? = null

        fun getInstance(context: Context): AppDatabase {
            return INSTANCE ?: synchronized(this) {
                val instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                    context.applicationContext,
                    AppDatabase::class.java,
                    "funiverse.sqlite"
                )
                    .createFromAsset("funiverse.sqlite") // Copy from assets
                    .addCallback(object : RoomDatabase.Callback() {
                        override fun onCreate(db: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
                            super.onCreate(db)
                            Log.d("Database", "Database created")
                        }
                        override fun onOpen(db: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
                            super.onOpen(db)
                            Log.d("Database", "Database opened")
                        }
                    })
                    .build()
                INSTANCE = instance
                instance

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Dao :

```
@Dao
interface EntertainmentDao {


    @Query("SELECT * FROM entertainment")
    fun getAllEntertainment(): List<Entertainment>


    @Query("SELECT * FROM entertainment WHERE categoryId = :categoryId")
    fun getEntertainmentByCategoryId(categoryId: Int): List<Entertainment>
}
```

Activity(Log with "Tag" gives result : 0 ) :

```
class EntertainmentActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityEntertainmentBinding
    private lateinit var db: AppDatabase
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        binding = ActivityEntertainmentBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)





        db = AppDatabase.getInstance(this)
        lifecycleScope.launch {
            val entertainmentList = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                db.entertainmentDao().getAllEntertainment()
            }

            updateUIWithEntertainmentList(entertainmentList)
            Log.e("tag",entertainmentList.size.toString())
        }




    }
    private fun updateUIWithEntertainmentList(entertainmentList: List<Entertainment>) {

        val adapter = EntertainmentAdapter(this, entertainmentList, object : ItemClickListener {
            override fun onImageClick(position: Int, image: String, text: String) {
                val bottomSheetFragment = BottomSheetFragment()
                val bundle = Bundle().apply {
                    putString("image_resource", image)
                    putString("text", text)
                }
                bottomSheetFragment.arguments = bundle
                bottomSheetFragment.show(supportFragmentManager, bottomSheetFragment.tag)
            }
        })

        binding.recyclerEasy.adapter = adapter
        binding.recyclerHard.adapter = adapter
        binding.recyclerMedium.adapter = adapter
    }

}
```

Comment: After running the App and trying to obtain data, does **`App Inspection`** show data in the database (showing the database in a tool only means that the data exists in the database in the tool not necessarily in the App). If App inspection shows data exists then you know that the asset has been successfully copied.

Comment: App inspection shows table (columns ) correctly , but table is empty . When i try to copy my .sqlite file from asset and open it in sqlite , i can see 3 records , but my project cannot see.